# I want to install cv2 using command prompt

Tags: python-3.x

how to install cv2 in python3 and python2
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: none)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# for python2

pip2 install opencv-python

# python3

pip3 install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt update
pip install opencv-python
```